# Obtener coordenadas X, Y de la imagen encontrada

Tags: python, imagen, python-3.7

Estoy usando la librería **pyautogui** para la búsqueda de imágenes, y el metodo ***locateOnScreen()*** para encontrar tal imagen en la pantalla,  he usado este codigo:

```
import pyutogui
imagen = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png') # devuelve los 4 valores del área en donde está la imagen

print(imagen)
```

Si encuentra la imagen me devuelve 4 valores que equivalen a **left**, **top**, **width**, **heigth**.
Quiero que me devuelva los 2 valores que equivaldrían a **(x, y)** en donde encontró la imagen, no el área en donde está posicionada y nosé que metodo, funcion o operacion tengo que implementar para sacar esos 2 valores, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: acaso `y` no será el `left`?

Comment: @Christian hice la prueba y el mouse queda mas lejos de lo normal

Comment: Haz probado con usar `locateCenterOnScreen`?

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya vi que con ese si funciona :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisando en la documentación [documentacion](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html?highlight=locate#the-locate-functions) , puedes utilizar center y así quedaría tu código:

```
imagen = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png')
resultado pyautogui.center(imagen)
```